# Is it possible to access js variables declared in your view from main.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I have some google analytics code in my application layout:

```
<%=javascript do %>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', '111111', 'xxxx.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

<%end%>

<%=javascript do %>
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '1111111']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xxxx.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

<%end%>
```

I need to somehow be able to access the "_gaq" variable from main.js to use for event tracking when a certain class is clicked. I'm trying to avoid an inline click handler here ,due to several complications.

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible, here is the documentation for Event Tracking:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

So you could do something like this:

```
$('.yourClassName').on('click', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);  //see google documentation for the paramters
});
```

Or do it inline, again see the Google Docs for specifics:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

I hope I answered your question accurately.

Answer (score 0):

You can save `_gaq` in `window._gaq` and then it will be available to all js files.

Comment: Do you mean "window"?